# I am trying to log in with entered otp in the OtpTextField package in flutter but it's not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using flutter with firebase and trying to send the OTP to a mobile number. The OTP was sent successfully, but while I was trying to enter the code and login to the app, I am unable to do so.

I get this error

> The verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid

How can I overcome this and how can I manually add a user's phone number in firebase.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_otp_text_field/flutter_otp_text_field.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:ranv1/Builder/builder_master.dart';
import 'package:ranv1/strings/colors.dart';

class ForOtp extends StatefulWidget {
  final String verificationId;

  const ForOtp({Key? key, required this.verificationId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ForOtpState createState() => _ForOtpState();
}

class _ForOtpState extends State<ForOtp> {
  final otpController = TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  void _signInWithPhoneNumber(String verificationId, String smsCode) async {
    try {
      final authCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: verificationId,
        smsCode: smsCode,
      );
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
      Get.to(() => const BuilderMaster());
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'OTP Verification',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Please enter the OTP sent to your registered mobile number',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              OtpTextField(
                onCodeChanged: (String code) {
                  // do nothing
                },
                numberOfFields: 6,
                fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                filled: true,
                focusedBorderColor: const Color(0xFFF54B64),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: rNavyGrey,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final smsCode = otpController.text.trim();
                    try {
                      // verify the entered OTP
                      final authCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                        verificationId: widget.verificationId,
                        smsCode: smsCode,
                      );
                      final userCredential =
                          await _auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential);

                      // navigate to the next page
                      Get.to(() => const BuilderMaster());
                    } catch (e) {
                      print(e);
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'SUBMIT',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```